# Using material ui and React, change the style of the `carrot` in TextField

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI `textfield` per the documentation here: https://mui.com/components/text-fields/. while there are plenty of docs on changing the font of the input text, I have yet to see any docs or resources on how to make the carrot fatter. I'm looking for a style that simulates the console, and I have provided an image below.  Below is the code for `textinput` I'm using, rather standard:

```
const translucent = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => createStyles({
    wrapForm : {
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        width: "95%",
        margin: `${theme.spacing(0)} auto`,
        // borderBottom: `0.8px solid ${translucent}`, // @TODO: remove this
    },
    wrapText  : {
        width: "100%"
    },
    button: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    multilineColor:{
        color:'white',
        borderColor: `white !important`,
        filter: 'blur(0.8px)'
    },
    overLayContainer: {
        display: 'grid',
    },

    overLayContainerInner: {
        gridArea: '1 / 1',
    },      
}));


/******************************************************
    @View
******************************************************/




export const TextInput = (props) => {

    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <>
            <form className={classes.wrapForm}  noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <TextField 
                    className = {classes.wrapForm}
                    fullWidth
                    multiline
                    InputProps={{className: classes.multilineColor, disableUnderline: true}}
                    rows   = "1"
                    margin = "normal"
                />
            </form>
        </>     
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that there's no documentation on how to make a fatter "caret" is because this is not currently supported in browsers. You can [change the caret color using CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color) (eg. `caret-color: red;`), but if you want to mimic a console's "fat" caret, you may have to add your own element to the screen and then move it based on the input entered.  [Here is an old example](http://shachi.prophp.org/demo.html?i=1) of one way to do it and [another](https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/YzGoBGq) which would also require your own JS implementation.

There is a [proposed revision](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-4/#propdef-caret-shape) for `caret-shape: block;`, which appears to be what you're looking for, but that is not currently supported.